# How dangerous is induction in my wires?

Tags: wiring, switch

I had to replace a cable going to a light switch. The cable was about 7m long and contained three (1.5mm^2) copper wires, with a distance of about 2mm between any two of them.

[image]
[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_cable#/media/File:Electric_guide_3%C3%972.5_mm.jpg)

One wire was the hot wire that constantly provided 230V, 50Hz alternating current to the switch, and one was going back to the light. The third one wasn't connected to anything.

[image]

I was very surprised to see that when the light was turned off (so only one of the three wires was powered), I could measure about 140V AC on the third wire compared to a grounded water pipe, using my super cheap multimeter. I didn't dare to touch it as long as any of it was powered.

I wondered, was this measurement of 140V realistic - or was my multimeter just faulty? And how much current could this cable have provided?

I have no idea how to estimate whether this was realistic so I'd be very happy to learn whether there are any formulas to approximate these values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key point in your question is that it happens when the light is off. In this case, the alternating current in the live wire produces an alternativing magnetic filed around the wire which induces current in the floating wire. This induced current is also 50hz that's why you can see it when your multimeter is in the AC mode.

The reason this voltage goes away when you turn on the light is that the second wire becomes live. Since the direction of current is opposite in the second wire its magnetic field is the opposite of that of the first live wire and it cancels the other magnetic field. I.e., one magnetic field is clockwise and the other counter clockwise at any moment in time. So no induced current.

When the light is off there is no current in the live wire so when you put any load on the float wire the induced voltage probably goes to 0.

Answer (score 4):

If the wire is not connected to anything, it is a floating wire and the voltage measured on such wire would depend on parasitics.

More specifically, there is some parasitic capacitance, $C_{fh}$, between the floating wire and the hot wire, as well as some parasitic capacitance, $C_{fn}$, between the floating wire and the neutral wire.

When you connect one probe of the voltmeter to the floating wire and the other probe to the ground, a voltage divider is formed between the hot wire and the ground and this voltage will be divided between $C_{fh}$ and $C_{fn}$ in parallel with the input impedance of the voltmeter.

The outcome will depend on the type and length of the cable and on the input impedance of the voltmeter, but you can easily measure some significant voltage there.

It is also possible that the cable is faulty ($140$V seems rather high), so don't make any assumptions without careful testing.

You can find some more details on the topic in [this post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/29394/why-am-i-measuring-16-volts-on-a-wire-that-should-be-at-0-volts) on the home improvement forum.

Comment: It's fairly normal to see DVMs indicate 60% of line voltage on a floating wire that is parallel to conductors. Of course as soon as you connect it to any kind of load, it disappears.... It's too bad the question departed the physics SE, I have always wondered how much useful energy could be picked up.

Answer (score 4):

It does sound like you are seeing induced voltage here, which is very commonly seen with house wiring when measured with a cheap multimeter.  It's often called "phantom voltage."  It will disappear if you connect the smallest load to it, and therefore is not dangerous.

Better meters for house wiring and other electrician type tasks have a low impedance (low Z) voltage test, in which the meter itself has low enough impedance that it will make these phantom voltages vanish.  The meter itself is enough of a load to make the induced voltage disappear.

Old fashioned solenoid voltage testers and most analog meters have enough impedance to keep you from getting fooled by induced voltages.  If you're going to work on house wiring, I'd strongly suggest a combination of a non-contact voltage tester and a solenoid type voltage tester, used properly these will keep you safe and give you enough info to troubleshoot.

This low Z test would not be desirable feature in some electronics work - in a delicate circuit with tiny working voltages the current the meter draws could disrupt the circuit you are testing.

There may be another problem here - it appears from your question that your ground wire is floating - that is it is not connected to anything, not bonded to the grounding system - and depending on the electrical system where you are, in most that green wire should be grounded properly for safety, but that's another question.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an induction effect. Your meter is not faulty. It is possible for significant voltages to be present between the neutral line and true ground in the absence of significant current flow in the circuit because of what else is connected to that neutral and how much current those things are drawing. This is a matter best discussed with a trained electrician.

Comment: This is not a neutral line, it is a line that is not connected to anything on both ends!

Comment: time to call that electrician!!!

Comment: OMG that's a new one- let's see if we can get some other responses from people who know more about this than I do.

Comment: Well it is gone now:) I added a diagram to hopefully clear things up!