# Converted 3 way switch to single pole. Disconnected traveler wire hot when fixture turned on

Tags: switch

I converted a three way switch in my dining room to a single pole smart switch and plan to put a blank wall plate where the old switch resided. I identified the common wire and the two travelers (one red, one black). At the switch that is being removed, I connected the black traveler wire to the other black wire that goes to the fixture.

The red traveler wire is now disconnected in both boxes, but when I turn the switch to on, my non-contact voltage tester shows that the disconnected red wire is hot in both boxes. How is this possible? Isn't it disconnected from all power sources?

Admittedly, I am an amateur and this is my first time doing this, but I understand (at least I thought I did) the concept here.

Comment: [Capacitive Coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitive_coupling). It's not really 'hot', it just looks that way to your non-contact tester.

Comment: Also described [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/29394/why-am-i-measuring-16-volts-on-a-wire-that-should-be-at-0-volts).  It's not capable of any useful work; if you connect a nightlight between red and neutral, it won't light.

Comment: Thanks @brhans and Harper. Good to know I'm not going to burn the house down.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I measuring 16 volts on a wire that should be at 0 volts?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/29394/why-am-i-measuring-16-volts-on-a-wire-that-should-be-at-0-volts)