# Low voltage ceiling fan wiring

Tags: ceiling-fan

I removed a HUNTER ceiling fan in my condo apartment. The fan wiring is preexisting.
I discovered that the fan is powered by 18-gauge wire and measures about 50 volts. I then checked other working fans and they are also powered by 18-gauge wire with 50 volts. The fan installation is about 30 years old.
Has anyone ever encountered a similar ceiling fan wiring system?

Comment: Is the 18 gauge wires from/attached to the fan or house/condo wires?  Does the fan have a label stating amps/watts, voltage?  50v seems low in a condo.  If so there should be a transformer powering the fans, or someone goofed up a lot.

Comment: where does 50 volts even come from in a house?

Comment: Are you replacing the fans because they abruptly failed?  50 volts is often seen on broken wires, is why I ask.

Comment: The fans are hardwired, that is the 18-gauge wires coming out of the ceiling go directly into the fans with no connectors.  There must be a transformer(s) somewhere, but it is not obvious where they are.  One of the fans failed, but three others are working.

Comment: Condo maintenance should have an idea, if not complete wiring diagrams.  The problem might be in finding replacements.

Comment: does the fan have a boxy speed control on the wall?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting 50V at a light when the switch is off?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/26456/why-am-i-getting-50v-at-a-light-when-the-switch-is-off)

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring in question?